# Date format is throwing up random numbers when using a function

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I am using a `INDEX, MATCH` function in sheet `Car Search` to pull data from sheet `Raw Data`. One of the cells is **Date Purchased**, this will show the date in format *dd/mm/yyyy* (UK Format).

The problem is, when I enter a date in this format, it doesn't correctly pull over to the `Car Search` sheet. Instead, it shows up `42350` when I entered `12/12/2015` in the `Raw Data` sheet. Both cells have been formatted to Date, but it is still showing up as 42350 and not 12/12/2015.

Is it because the function is preventing it from showing date format? Anybody know why Excel does this? I have tried on a new sheet, but same result.

Please see images below.

[image: Car Search Sheet]
[image: Raw Data Sheet]

Comment: `42350` is the difference in days between  12/12/2015 and 1/1/1900 (off by one due to a deliberately introduced error counting 1900 as a leap year).  That is how Excel stores dates.  So all you need to do is format that cell to show a date.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the cell's format to 'Date' and it will be correct.

When you type a function in cell, Excel adjusts the format of the cell according to the function. This is often correct and useful, but sometimes not.

Here, Excel thinks that the result of the INDEX function is a number, and changes the cell format to 'Number' *whenever you type or change the formula*. So you might have to repeat the 'set format to date' when you edit the formula (not the input values, the formula itself). However, once the formula is correct, that would not be needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Go to the Formulas tab in tool bar. Then in the "Formula Audit" section deselect "fxShowFormulas"